# C++ Data Structure that would be best to hold a large list of names

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

Can you share your thoughts on what the best STL data structure would be for storing a large list of names and perform searches on these names?

Edit:
The names are not unique and the list can grow as new names can continuously added to it.  And by large I am talking of from 1 million to 10 million names.

Comment: Are the names unique?  Are you creating this container once and then searching many times or is there some amount of adding/deleting items as well as the searches?  Do you need to iterate through the container in alphabetical order?

Comment: Dynamic array or std::vector (physically the same). set and linked list are not suitable for large number of elements because the add time is too long.

Comment: Also, how large is large?  If it is only a few million names that are 10's of characters long, std::map is probably fine on a reasonably provisioned laptop.  If you need several billion names each of which is 100's of characters long, or if you have a memory constrained system, you might need an out-of-core solution, which may preclude STL (though Google finds http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/, which claims to handle that case).

Comment: Boost Flyweight Library http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/flyweight/doc/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to search names, you want a structure that support fast random access. That means vector, deque and list are all out of the question. Also, vector/array are slow on random adds/inserts for sorted sets because they have to shift items to make room for each inserted item. Adding to end is very fast, though.

Consider `std::map`, `std::unordered_map` or `std::unordered_multimap` (or their siblings `std::set`, `std::unordered_set` and `std::unordered_multiset` if you are only storing keys).

If you are purely going to do unique, random access, I'd start with one of the unordered_* containers.

If you need to store an ordered list of names, and need to do range searches/iteration and sorted operations, a tree based container like `std::map` or `std::set` should do better with the iteration operation than a hash based container because the former will store items adjacent to their logical predecessors and successors. For random access, it is O(log N) which is still decent.

Prior to std::unordered_*, I used `std::map` to hold large numbers of objects for an object cache and though there are faster random access containers, it scaled well enough for our uses. The newer unordered_map has O(1) access time so it is a hashed structure and should give you the near best access times.

Comment: If all he has is a list of strings and nothing to map them to then the various `set` containers are a better choice.

Comment: But what is he going to map the names to?

Comment: I wasn't sure if he needed to store a record, or if the name is the record. I'm sure he can substitute the corresponding set alternative as needed. In any case, if you feel the answer would be improved by me referencing the set* siblings, I will edit it.

Comment: Unless the question is improved or you like writing books, I think this is the best you're going to do. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the possibility of using concatenation of those names using a delimiter but the searching might take a hit. You would need to come up with a adjusted binary searching.

But you should try the obvious solution first which is a hashmap which is called unordered_map in stl. See if that meets your needs. Searching should be plenty fast there but at a cost of memory.